# Chrome PreRender Redirect

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, prerender

I'm having a very hard time testing PreRender in chrome.  Let's say I have some page that contains nothing, besides the following

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com";
```

If I point to the above described page with a PreRender tester, such as this one [google tools](https://prerender-test.appspot.com/) it doesn't process the redirect.

More surprising still, if I put a delay/timeout on the redirect, I must wait the entire time for the redirect to trigger.

I'm confused because I'm told by Google and others that PreRender renders the page "just like" it was opened as a "hidden tab" of a tab that was opened but not called to focus.

Comment: I find current behavior perfectly logical if you consider that it's url-based, not UI tab-based. THE page is empty and should be shown even if for a moment as such,  *just like* it would be during normal browsing. The prerenderer rendered it. Any subsequently redirected url is an entirely different page.

Comment: I'm not following, nor am I sure what you mean the page. Right click a link with a redirect in it and click open in new tab. The new tab will load the initial page, and the redirect all while out of view. Why doesn't PreRender emulate this behavior?  Is the jist of your comment that when the PreRender tool hits a redirect it ceases--if so, why?

Comment: Page is a webpage. It is defined by its url. You're confusing tabs with pages.

Comment: I'm just not sure what is going on. How does the PreRender tool know to run some JavaScript but not JavaScript that results in navigating to a new page? I could see it hanging off an instant before redirecting, but if the redirect is behind a 5 second timeout, it doesn't even start the timer until I View the page

Comment: Obviously, all timers that exceed page load time are frozen. Seems logical to me because once the page is prerendered it must keep its state to be shown *just like* it would look normally. As for blocking navigation, it's just blocked temporarily in the browser, not in js, so there's no magical analyzer of the code.

Comment: Interesting.  So, the page isn't loaded?  Page load only occurs once it is visible.  Either way, it may make sense, but it's not well explained by googles "just like a hidden tab" metaphor...